# When selling my own cover version of a song, is it legal to mention its appearance in a film for promotion?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, music

Let's say I wish to record my own version of the song *Girl, You'll Be a Woman Soon*.

It is obvious that I'm required to pay royalties to the original owner of the song.

But while promoting my song, am I allowed to mention the fact that the original version was used in *Pulp Fiction*?

For example, can I write on my online shop "Buy my version of the tune from Pulp Fiction"?

Comment: What's the jurisdiction? Also, where would you be mentioning the appearance? On the cover, or somewhere else?

Comment: Your cover version was in Pulp Fiction?

Comment: @HDE226868 I'd sell it internationally (online) from my hometown in Israel. I added an example to make things clearer.

Comment: LOL that the original was in Pulp Fiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing about copyright that keeps you from referencing something else.

Your statement DOES however begin to tread in the realm of deceptive advertising...depending on how you word it, giving the imoression that your recording was in the movie. (when it was not).

For example, "Please download my version of the song "Doin' Allright," one of the songs played at Woodstock."   A reader can easily imagine that they're getting the sound recording from Woodstock, much to their shock and dismay when they actually listen to it!

Comment: I also talked to a lawyer about it (unofficially) and she gave me a similar answer.